# Editing .vimrc on Mac OSX results in bort trap

Tags: macos, vim

**EDIT: The problem was that I didn't realize that vim comes installed on Mac, so I used fink to install it and had two instances of vim, and I guess that never mattered until I started playing around with the .vimrc file.**

I've just started using vim in the terminal in Mac (previously been using MacVim's GUI and emacs in terminal). Pretty much whatever I do to my .vimrc file makes subsequent running of vim result in "bort trap". This is the only output after crashing.

An empty .vimrc file also doesn't work, as well as a file with one space. The only thing that's worked is if I do ":set ruler" and then "mkv" in vim to make a .vimrc file that looks like this:

```
version 6.0
if !&cp | set cp | endif
let s:cpo_save=&cpo 
set cpo&vim
map! <D-v> ^V^R*
vmap <BS> "-d
vmap <D-x> "*d 
vmap <D-c> "*y
vmap <D-v> "-d"*P
nmap <D-v> "*P
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
set helplang=de
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
set ruler
" vim: set ft=vim :
```

No .vimrc file at all also works. :P I've tried ":set nocompatible" followed by "mkv", which results in a .vimrc file that makes vim crash. What is going on?

vim --version outputs:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2b BETA (2008 Jul 13, compiled May 27 2011 18:38:12)
MacOS X (unix) Version
```

Comment: Where are you saving your `.vimrc` file?

Comment: /Users/Sarah. That's where it automatically saves when I do "mkv" as well.

Comment: IIRC, a vote to close automatically makes a downvote, and the reason someone voted to close was that this question is fairly vague and difficult to follow. Things that might help: run vim from the command line, copy/paste the crash message (or the useful bits), clearly explain what you've done and tried to do.

Comment: So your ~/.vimrc is empty and vim crashes? Or you have a stable file and then making changes causes it to crash? Please be more specific. Do you have any plugins running? What version of vim are you running (`vim --version` from the command line)?

Comment: Literally the only output after crashing is "bort trap". I've edited my original question to be more clear. Thanks for the tips Wayne; Personally I find the stackoverflow community has been really unfriendly to me...

Comment: I don't know if I'm running any plugins..? vim --version outputs:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2b BETA (2008 Jul 13, compiled May 27 2011 18:38:12)
MacOS X (unix) Version

Comment: Don't bother installing CLI Vim either through Macports or Fink. There is a supercharged (and fast) CLI Vim in the MacVim bundle that will honor your `~/.vimrc` as long as it is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming your `.vimrc`, creating a blank file in its place and running vim? If that works, you can copy back sections from the original (assuming you want those settings) bit by bit to find where the problem is.

Comment: Also, can you upgrade to a non-Beta version of Vim? That might help.